# Pattern matching problems involving FullForm and Plus and Times

Tags: symbolic, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I am trying to match an expression that will be a sum of more than one terms, with the last one being a product. For example, the object`a+b+x*y`. I am using the FullForm of the expression, which is the form `Plus[a,b,Times[x,y]]`. After reviewing documentation, pattern `Plus[__,Times[_]]` seems to be what I am looking for, and it gives correct result:

[image]

However, when I apply `FullForm` to the expression before trying the match, the pattern fails.

[image]

¿Why does this happen? I thought that the `FullForm` evaluation was performed beforehand.

Comment: Take a look at `FullForm[Plus[a, b, Times[x, y]]] // FullForm`. So you have to modify the pattern. e.g. `MatchQ[FullForm[Plus[a, b, Times[x, y]]], _[Plus[__, Times[_]]]]`

Comment: Your have more problems beyond the misuse of `FullForm`.  See my answer below for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside following the good advice Rohit Namjoshi has given in a comment, you need to become aware that pattern matching against `Plus`and `Times` is tricky because these operators have attributes (special rules) that cause strange things to happen when the patterns containing them are evaluated.

Consider the following:

You don't want

```
MatchQ[Plus[a, b, foo[x, y]], Plus[__, Times[_]]]
```

to return `True` but it does. The reason for this is that

```
Plus[__, Times[_]] // FullForm
```

gives

```
    Plus[Blank[], BlankSequence[]]
```

which will match any `Plus` expression with two or moore arguaments. What you want is something like

```
MatchQ[Plus[a, b, Times[x, y]], Plus[__, Times[__]]]
```

but that doesn't work either because

```
Plus[__, Times[__]] // FullForm
```

gives

```
    Times[2, BlankSequence[]]
```

So what to do? I recommend using `Inactivate`.

```
Inactivate[MatchQ[a + b + x*y, Plus[__, Times[__]]], Plus | Times]
(* True *)

Inactivate[MatchQ[a + a + x*x, Plus[__, Times[__]]], Plus | Times]
(* True *)

Inactivate[MatchQ[a + b + foo[x, y], Plus[__, Times[__]]], Plus | Times]
(* False *)
```

#### Update

On second thought perhaps using `HoldPattern` is better.

```
MatchQ[a + b + x*y, HoldPattern[Plus[__, Times[__]]]]
(* True *)

MatchQ[a + a + x*x, HoldPattern[Plus[__, Times[__]]]]
(* True *)

MatchQ[a + b + foo[x, y], HoldPattern[Plus[__, Times[__]]]]
(* False *)
```